How can i fix the score saving method in unity3d c# project?
i managed to create a simple clicker game in unity3d.
At the beggining everything worked, clicking, score saving method etc.
Then i wanted to add a shop,that will upgrade the user mouse power click (basically more score added for every click). Right now it works and not works, When debugging, aftec buying an upgrade it says that it saved the correct score , but when im closing the shop or clicking again, it saves the score  that was before buying the upgrade.
Any fixes?
StrawberryClicker.cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using System.Collections;

public class StrawberryClicker : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Button clickButton;
    public Text clickCountText;
    public Text dropTimeText;

    private int clickCount = 0;
    private int mousePower = 1;
    private float clickTime = 0;
    private float dropTimer = 0;
    private float dropInterval = 3 * 3600; // 3 hours in seconds
    private float idleDropInterval = 18 * 3600; // 18 hours in seconds
    private bool isClicking = false;
    private float lastClickTime = 0;
    private string userId;

    void Start()
{
    clickButton.onClick.AddListener(OnClick);

    userId = LocalStorageManager.GetUserId();
    // Load the score when the game starts
    LoadScore();

    mousePower = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MousePower", 1);

    // Automatically save score every 5 seconds
    InvokeRepeating("SaveScore", 5f, 5f);
}

    public void StartSavingScore()
    {
        InvokeRepeating("SaveScore", 5f, 5f);
    }

    public void StopSavingScore()
    {
        CancelInvoke("SaveScore");
    }

    void Update()
    {
        clickTime += Time.deltaTime;
        if (isClicking)
        {
            lastClickTime = clickTime;
            if (clickTime - dropTimer >= dropInterval)
            {

            }
        }
        else if (clickTime - lastClickTime >= 60)
        {
            if (clickTime - dropTimer >= idleDropInterval)
            {

            }
        }

        dropTimeText.text = $"Next Drop In: {(dropInterval - (clickTime - dropTimer)) / 3600:F2} hours";
    }

        // Add this variable
    public int ClickCount { get { return clickCount; } }

    // Modify OnClick method
    void OnClick()
    {
        clickCount += mousePower;
        isClicking = true;
        clickCountText.text = $"Clicks: {clickCount}";

        // Add this line to update click count in ShopManager
        FindObjectOfType<ShopManager>().UpdateClickCount(clickCount);
    }

    public void SaveScore()
    {
        LocalStorageManager.SaveScore(clickCount);
    }

    void LoadScore()
    {
        clickCount = LocalStorageManager.LoadScore();
        clickCountText.text = $"Clicks: {clickCount}";
    }
}


ShopManager.cs
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class ShopManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    public GameObject shopPanel;
    public Button shopButton;
    public Button closeButton;
    public Button buyMousePowerButton;
    public Text clickCountText;
    public Text mousePowerText;

    private int clickCount;
    private int mousePower = 1;
    private int mousePowerCost = 50;
    private int mousePowerBought = 0;

    // Add this variable
    private StrawberryClicker strawberryClicker;

    void Start()
    {
        // Add these lines to update the click count when the shop is opened
        strawberryClicker = FindObjectOfType<StrawberryClicker>();
        clickCount = strawberryClicker.ClickCount;
        UpdateUI();

        mousePower = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MousePower", 1);
        mousePowerBought = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("MousePowerBought", 0);

        shopPanel.SetActive(false);

        shopButton.onClick.AddListener(OpenShop);
        closeButton.onClick.AddListener(CloseShop);
        buyMousePowerButton.onClick.AddListener(BuyMousePower);
    }


    // Add this method to update click count when it changes in StrawberryClicker
    public void UpdateClickCount(int newClickCount)
    {
        clickCount = newClickCount;
        UpdateUI();
    }


    void UpdateUI()
    {
        clickCountText.text = $"Clicks: {clickCount}";
        mousePowerText.text = $"Mouse Power: {mousePower} (Bought: {mousePowerBought})";
    }

    public void OpenShop()
    {
        shopPanel.SetActive(true);
        // Stop saving the score when the shop is opened
        FindObjectOfType<StrawberryClicker>().StopSavingScore();
    }

    public void CloseShop()
    {
        // Save the score before closing the shop
        FindObjectOfType<StrawberryClicker>().SaveScore();
        shopPanel.SetActive(false);
        // Resume saving the score when the shop is closed
        FindObjectOfType<StrawberryClicker>().StartSavingScore();
    }

    public void BuyMousePower()
{
    Debug.Log("BuyMousePower() called");
    Debug.Log($"clickCount: {clickCount}, mousePowerCost: {mousePowerCost}");

    if (clickCount >= mousePowerCost)
    {
        Debug.Log("Purchase successful");
        clickCount -= mousePowerCost;
        mousePower++;
        mousePowerBought++;
        // Save the updated score immediately after the purchase
        LocalStorageManager.SaveScore(clickCount);
        // Update the UI with the new score
        UpdateUI();
        // Save the mouse power and mouse power bought values
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MousePower", mousePower);
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("MousePowerBought", mousePowerBought);
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Insufficient clicks to purchase Mouse Power");
    }
}

}


LocalStorageManager.cs
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;

public class LocalStorageManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static string userIdKey = "user_id";
    private static string scoreKey = "score";

    // Define your secret key here
    private static readonly string secretKey = "s3cr3tK3y@123"; // Replace this with a securely generated key

    public static string GetUserId()
    {
        if (!PlayerPrefs.HasKey(userIdKey))
        {
            string newUserId = GenerateUserId();
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(userIdKey, newUserId);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
            return newUserId;
        }
        else
        {
            return PlayerPrefs.GetString(userIdKey);
        }
    }

    public static void SaveScore(int score)
    {
        string encryptedScore = Encrypt(score.ToString());
        PlayerPrefs.SetString(scoreKey, encryptedScore);
        PlayerPrefs.Save();
        Debug.Log($"Score saved: {score}");
    }

    public static int LoadScore()
    {
        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey(scoreKey))
        {
            string encryptedScore = PlayerPrefs.GetString(scoreKey);
            string decryptedScore = Decrypt(encryptedScore);
            if (int.TryParse(decryptedScore, out int score))
            {
                Debug.Log($"Score loaded: {score}");
                return score;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("No score found, returning default score 0");
        return 0; // Default score if not found
    }

    private static string GenerateUserId()
    {
        return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
    }

    private static string Encrypt(string plainText)
    {
        byte[] data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(plainText);
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
            {
                Key = keys,
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateEncryptor();
                byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                return Convert.ToBase64String(results, 0, results.Length);
            }
        }
    }

    private static string Decrypt(string cipherText)
    {
        byte[] data = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
        using (MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider())
        {
            byte[] keys = md5.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secretKey));
            using (TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider tripDes = new TripleDESCryptoServiceProvider()
            {
                Key = keys,
                Mode = CipherMode.ECB,
                Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7
            })
            {
                ICryptoTransform transform = tripDes.CreateDecryptor();
                byte[] results = transform.TransformFinalBlock(data, 0, data.Length);
                return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(results);
            }
        }
    }
}


I tried remaking the ints into public, importing them from the main script (strawberryclicker.cs), asking chatgpt, looking for the answers myself and nothing worked. The expectation of the score being one for all methods failed. That's why i ask you guys, maybe here I will find some help here.

well your shopmanager never saves the playerprefs..

What about LocalStorageManager.SaveScore(clickCount);?

thats not your shop manager though :p

Thanks, fixed it by changing
LocalStorageManager.SaveScore(clickCount);
to
string encryptedScore = LocalStorageManager.Encrypt(clickCount.ToString());
            PlayerPrefs.SetString(LocalStorageManager.scoreKey, encryptedScore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();

and adding
clickCount = LocalStorageManager.LoadScore();
        clickCountText.text = $"Clicks: {clickCount}";

to CloseShop()
